# How to group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group rows in my tables in MySQL

I have the following database setup:

[image: database setup]

I would like to get the event with the highest id which has a specific `user_id` (such as '3') either as the `organiser.user_id` or the `helper.user_id`.

I am not sure how to go around doing this as I am fairly new to MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result [mre]

Answer (score 0):

you can either join event_helpers or event_organisers to events table.
then specific user_id and order by event id get the top one

```sql
select 
    events.* from events 
    inner join event_helpers on (event_helpers.event_id=events.id) 
    where event_helpers.user_id=3 
    order by events.id desc limit 1
```

Comment: This seems to address one half of the problem only

Answer (score 0):

the following should do the trick. As there's no examplary data I cannot vouch for it entirely. also I haven't actually ran the code against a database so it could contain minor errors.

In short i'm doing:

- select all from the events table.
- join the organisers table on event_id
- limit results to only show rows with a joined user_id of 3
- order rows descending (highest first)
- limit the result to retrieve only one

```
SELECT * 
FROM events
LEFT JOIN event_organisers ON event_organisers.event_id = events.id
LEFT JOIN event_helpers ON event_helpers.event_id = events.id
WHERE event_organisers.user_id = 3
OR event_helpers.user_id = 3
ORDER BY events.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This should get you the result you're looking for. Or at least it should get you going.

Comment: This seems to address one half of the problem only

Comment: I don't see another half in the question? Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is great except I am wanting to get the latest one where the person could be an organiser or a helper

Comment: Don't have time at the moment to edit my answer but I will when I have time, for now: you can join both tables (use a left join now) and add an OR statement for the user_id on the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Such lookups are usually done with `IN` or `EXISTS`.

```
select *
from events
where id in (select event_id from event_helpers where user_id = 3)
   or id in (select event_id from event_organisers where user_id = 3)
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

`IN` or `EXISTS` often perform better than joins (though I don't expect this to be the case with the given task), but queries with an `OR` condition are often rather slow, because indexes might not be used as would be desired. Another option that may or may not perform better:

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from events
  where id = (select max(event_id) from event_helpers where user_id = 3)
  union all
  select *
  from events 
  where id = (select max(event_id) from event_organisers where user_id = 3)
) newest_two
order by id desc
limit 1;
```